# If join blocks the main thread, why it doesn't block in loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

The join() method of a Thread instance can be used to "join" the start of a thread's execution to the end of another thread's execution so that a thread will not start running until another thread has ended. If join() is called on a Thread instance, the currently running thread will block until the Thread instance has finished executing

But if i a have multiple threads and when I call join inside the loop. All threads run in parallel. But according to join concept first joined thread should finish then only main thread should allow to join the other threads.

```
public class MultiThreading implements Runnable {


private int name;
public MultiThreading(int number) {
    name =number;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ) {

           System.out.println("Thread number :" + name +" Printed value "+i);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final Thread[] workers = new Thread[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        workers[i] = new Thread(new MultiThreading(i));
    }
    for (final Thread t : workers) {
        t.start();

    }

    for (final Thread t : workers) {
        t.join();
        System.out.println("Thread joind to main thread : " + t.getName());
    }
    System.out.println("Main thread ends");
}
```

}

In the above code, if the first thread is joined then the main thread should be blocked and it shouldn't let other thread to join (until the joined thread finished the execution of run method). But all the threads are joined in parallel. The output is like -

```
Thread number :0 Printed value 0
Thread number :1 Printed value 0
Thread number :2 Printed value 0
Thread number :0 Printed value 1
Thread number :1 Printed value 1
Thread number :2 Printed value 1
Thread number :0 Printed value 2
Thread number :1 Printed value 2
Thread number :2 Printed value 2
Thread number :0 Printed value 3
Thread number :1 Printed value 3
Thread number :2 Printed value 3
Thread number :0 Printed value 4
Thread number :1 Printed value 4
Thread number :2 Printed value 4
Thread number :1 Printed value 5
Thread number :0 Printed value 5
Thread number :2 Printed value 5
Thread number :0 Printed value 6
Thread number :1 Printed value 6
Thread number :2 Printed value 6
Thread number :1 Printed value 7
Thread number :0 Printed value 7
Thread number :2 Printed value 7
Thread number :0 Printed value 8
Thread number :1 Printed value 8
Thread number :2 Printed value 8
Thread number :1 Printed value 9
Thread number :0 Printed value 9
Thread number :2 Printed value 9
Thread number :1 Printed value 10
Thread number :0 Printed value 10
Thread number :2 Printed value 10
Thread joind to main thread : Thread-0
Thread joind to main thread : Thread-1
Thread joind to main thread : Thread-2
Main thread ends
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GhostCat I see the output of the program, I don't understand what the OP is expecting.

Comment: @MauricePerry in join loop if the first thread is joined why the main thread is not blocked. it is allowing other thread to join even before first joined thread finishes.

Comment: @AnshulKabra the main thread IS blocked until the first thread ends.

Comment: @GhostCat  Thank you so much for quick clarification. The reason I got confused is that the threads are doing the same stuff. I made the second thread to run for a little longer.

Comment: You are very welcome. And albeit a bit unclear, I think you put up a nice question, and thanks for the quick accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all:

> The join() method of a Thread instance can be used to "join" the start of a thread's execution to the end of another thread's execution

That is a misconception: this has nothing to do with **starting** Threads. Join only does this: a **running** thread will wait until the other thread has ended.

When you do `someThread.join()`, then the thread invoking that method will wait until someThread has ended!

> But all the threads are joined in parallel.

Yes, because they are all done.

Your threads do all the exact same thing, so besides a few nanoseconds here or there (which are mostly invalidated due to the fact that writing to System.out effectively synchronizes stuff anyway) they all need the same amount of time.

So by the time you join the first thread ... the other two threads will be done. So the first call to `join()` makes the "main" thread wait for the first thread to end, and the subsequent calls happen "instantly", because these threads are done, too.

In order to delay things, make the number of loops a parameter of your `MultiThreading` class, and then ensure that your threads will require for different amounts of time. If Thread-0 does 10 loops, and Thread-1 goes 20, and the Thread-2 will do 30, you will see that each join does in fact wait for the corresponding thread to end.

Long story short: you **start** all your threads immediately, thus they instantly start running in parallel. The later join call simply delays the **main** thread from progressing, until each of the worker threads has ended.

Comment: IMO, You should remove the idea of "main thread" or "active thread" from this answer. They only confuse things. A `t.join()` call won't return until thread `t` has terminated.  Is there anything else about `join()` that a newbie needs to know?

Comment: P.S., I am quietly crusading to eliminate "current thread" from our vocabulary. It meant something in kernel code back when a computer had only one CPU, and the authors of user-mode code could easily understand it to mean, "the caller." But, what does "current thread" mean when the system has four or sixteen or sixty-some CPUs all hard at work? I think we could help the newbies a lot by saying, "the caller," or "the calling thread," wherever that makes sense.